# Vegas Pro 15.0 Fade In/Out

Tags: video, editing, vegas-pro

[image]

Hi everyone! Unfortunately, I have no idea how to search for a solution so I will try to explain what my problem is. For some reason, on some video, I cannot add fade in/out, because it is overlapped by another one. Is there any way to fix this instead of leaving a small gap between videos?

Comment: Indeed, Vegas sometimes does not allow to fade the clip when there is another one on the same track, and I could not find logic to this. The simplest choice is to move it into a separate track, where fade always works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... You could try to place the clip that you want to fade in/out on top of the other clips. If that does not work, you will have to split all of the clips at the same place and make them all fade in/out. If doing this will ruin the whole project video because you have other effects on it, then I suggest rendering the video without adding any fade in-/outs and then opening a new project and adding the video you made, then making it fade in/out wherever you would like to. I hope this helped!